# How to expose a Flask local development(default) server to the public on windows server

Tags: rest, api, web-deployment, windows-server-2012, flask-restful

I have a flask app running on a remote WINDOWS server (this server has a fixed ip address) which is not on my local network. The flask app is used to return some json data. The app works fine when I try to access the data while being logged into the remote server through request module in Python. However, when I try to run the same script on my personal laptop (which is not on the same network as the remote windows server), I get an error. However, when I try to ping the remote server from windows command prompt, I get the answer back. Can somebody tell in which direction should I go? I have no experience with web / api development.

```
    response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/product/1)
```

But instead of the local ip address, if I substitute the remote ip address, I don't get anything back.

Comment: Can you provide some information regarding the firewall settings that might be between the server and your local laptop? Also, what WSGI server are you using to host the Flask application? If you have a configuration file for your WSGI server, that might be helpful.

Comment: Hello, I am only using the default development server that comes with Flask. My current goal is to get data from the remote server just to demonstrate something and I am still far away from production stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem lied with the remote firewall, it was blocking incoming connections. The moment I switched off the firewall, everything started working.